# find out the loading mechanism for an oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am dealing with a black box. It is an oracle db. There is no documentation. On top of that i have no experience on `oracle dbs`, the only thing i know is that it is using `odi` to implement the loading flows. Is there any way to pick a table and back track the loading process? How am i going to find which package loads the table?

Is there any sql statement which can lead me to the loading method? How can i reverse engineer this?

For example, in `sql server` i would check the `sql agent` to find the job which loads the table, or query the `SSIS metadata` to find the package which includes the given table. Is there something similar in oracle?

Comment: We don't know anything about your database either... most importantly, what it's used for. Is it a data warehouse? I would look for DB and os level jobs for starters.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would try:

```
    select * from dba_source 
    where upper(text) like '%<your_table_name_in_caps>%' 
    and owner != 'SYS';
```

This *might* point you to objects (packages, functions, procedures, triggers etc.) that reference the table in question. Hopefully that gives you some direction. If `dba_source` (text source of all stored objects in the database) doesn't work, try `all_source` (objects accessible to the current user).

You may also be able to query some of the hist tables (`dba_hist_sqltext`, `dba_hist_active_sess_history` etc.) to check programs that recently accessed this table or check any scheduled jobs (`dba_scheduler_jobs`).

These are all blind hits though and may bring in irrelevant results depending on your specific case. Good luck and come back here if you need more help.